# How do I move multiple values out of a boxed value without calling clone?

Tags: rust

I have a boxed tuple to avoid recursion. However, when I pattern match against the tuple, I can't seem to get at both tuple values. To illustrate my problem, take [the following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=612cee39c059b5c047973a67e1d9b236&version=stable&mode=debug):

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Foo {
    Base,
    Branch(Box<(Foo, Foo)>),
}

fn do_something(f: Foo) -> Foo {
    match f {
        Foo::Base => Foo::Base,
        Foo::Branch(pair) => {
            let (f1, f2) = *pair;
            if f2 == Foo::Base {
                f1
            } else {
                f2
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo::Branch(Box::new((Foo::Base, Foo::Base)));
    println!("{:?}", do_something(f));
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `pair`
  --> src/main.rs:11:22
   |
11 |             let (f1, f2) = *pair;
   |                  --  ^^ value used here after move
   |                  |
   |                  value moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because `pair.0` has type `Foo`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I've read about boxed syntax, but I'd like to avoid unstable features if at all possible. It feels like the only answer is redefining `Branch` as

```
Branch(Box<Foo>, Box<Foo>)
```

but this seems like it avoids answering the question (which is admittedly mostly a thought exercise at this point).

Comment: Given the answers, I would expect this qualifies as a bug of rustc. You might want to open a bug report so that it is checked and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed when [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) were introduced. The original code now compiles as-is:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Foo {
    Base,
    Branch(Box<(Foo, Foo)>),
}

fn do_something(f: Foo) -> Foo {
    match f {
        Foo::Base => Foo::Base,
        Foo::Branch(pair) => {
            let (f1, f2) = *pair;
            if f2 == Foo::Base {
                f1
            } else {
                f2
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo::Branch(Box::new((Foo::Base, Foo::Base)));
    println!("{:?}", do_something(f));
}
```

This was tracked in [issue 16223](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16223).

Answer (score 1):

Unboxing in two steps works:

```
fn do_something(f: Foo) -> Foo {
    match f {
        Foo::Base => Foo::Base,
        Foo::Branch(pair) => {
            let pair = *pair;
            let (f1, f2) = pair;
            if f2 == Foo::Base {
                f1
            } else {
                f2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing within curly braces also works.

```
fn do_something(f: Foo) -> Foo {
    match f {
        Foo::Base => Foo::Base,
        Foo::Branch(pair) => {
            let (f1, f2) = { *pair };
            if f2 == Foo::Base {
                f1
            } else {
                f2
            }
        }
    }
}
```